# Android: Add audio and image files downloaded from server to app data

Tags: android, image, file, audio, save

I am creating an app where the user will find a topic of interest, and download audio and images related to this topic stored using NoSQL database. I don't want the user to have direct access to the file after downloading, since the content should belong to the creator. The data should be downloaded, not streaming, as in some cases the user may not have internet access.

I wasn't sure how to go about this. I thought the files could be downloaded to the resources folder for each instance of the app. First, I could not find how to do this, and I also wasn't sure if I would reach a maximum memory limit.

An alternative I thought of was to encrypt the files then decrypt them within the app.

Thanks!

Alex

Comment: Have a look at getFilesDir().

Comment: It seems like that finds the directory where files are stored. Does this mean if I store files in that directory, they'll be only accessible to my app? I'm new to android, so this may be a very basic question.

Comment: Indeed basic. And indeed private storage to your app.

Comment: @greenapps, great, thanks :)